# Could not find a declaration file for module 'connect-session-knex'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I'm getting this error

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'connect-session-knex'.

[image]

```
import KnexSessionStore from 'connect-session-knex';

const knexSession = KnexSessionStore(session);
```

And i do this

`console.log(KnexSessionStore);`

and it returns

> [function]

I'm using this package https://github.com/llambda/connect-session-knex

And yes the package is installed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it come from the import mode. If this module is old and not updated to last nodeJS features maybe he is just not compatible with ESimport style and require nodeJS style import ?

Comment: I did the old way of doing it, using `require` but i still get the error. thanks though.

Comment: Then from what i'm seeing, this seems to be typescript related ? Are you using typescript ?

Comment: its es6 babel, ill link the github https://github.com/EliHood/es6expresscrudreact